# Add row in excel every time function is called in JAVA

Tags: java, excel, file, apache-poi

I am using this code to add row at the end of the Excel sheet. Every time function is called. Where `last=0` at initialization.

```
connectionTime, mobility, angleofArrival, sender and peer
```

are some variables which values is changed with function calling. and there value i want to save in each row, when function is called.

```
public void excelWriter(DTNHost sender, DTNHost peer){
         String fileName = "Results.xls";      

            try {

                            File file = new File(fileName);
                            FileInputStream fin = null;  
                            HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;  
                            HSSFSheet worksheet = null;  
                            FileOutputStream fout = null;
                            POIFSFileSystem lPOIfs = null;
                            if (file.exists()) {
                                try{
                                    fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true);
                                    fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                                    lPOIfs = new POIFSFileSystem(fin);
                                    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(lPOIfs);
                                    worksheet = workbook.getSheet("POI Worksheet");

                                    for (int i=0; i<workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                                        System.out.println( workbook.getSheetName(i) );                                    
                                    }
                                    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                                    last = sheet.getLastRowNum();
                                }catch (IOException e) {  
                                    e.printStackTrace();  
                                }catch (NullPointerException e){
                                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                                }
                            } else {
                                //create new file
                                try{
                                fout = new FileOutputStream(file);                            
                                }catch (IOException e) {  
                                    e.printStackTrace();  
                                }
                                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();                       
                                worksheet = workbook.createSheet("POI Worksheet");  
                            }

                            if(last != 0){
                                last = worksheet.getLastRowNum();
                            }else{

                                last = worksheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
                                System.out.println(last);

                            }

                HSSFRow row = worksheet.createRow(last++);                  
                HSSFCell cellA1 = row.createCell((int)0);
                cellA1.setCellValue(sender+" and "+peer);               
                HSSFCell cellB1 = row.createCell((int) 1);
                cellB1.setCellValue(mobility);      
                HSSFCell cellC1 = row.createCell((int) 2);
                cellC1.setCellValue(angleOfArival);
                HSSFCell cellD1 = row.createCell((int) 3);
                cellD1.setCellValue(connectionTime);    
                System.out.println("Data written");
                workbook.write(fout);
                fout.flush();

                fout.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




           ////End
    }
```

But it adds just one row (Only first time). I have done debugging of it. `last` value is increased every time function is called but row is not added every time. Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Can you post your complete code?

Comment: it is the code which I am using to write data in excel. the unknown values are variables. Which could be dummy values, I change them in question. to make it more clear. Whole code is above 500 lines and irrelevant  too as well

Comment: `fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true);` Please have a look at the file. Its size should increase rapidly since you are appending complete Workbooks one after the other every time the code runs. Don't use append mode here. `Workbook.write` writes the complete workbook every time.

Comment: You told what not to do. but so what should i do then.

Comment: `fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName)`

Comment: It shows this exception if i remove true. "Unable to read entire header; 0 bytes read; expected 512 bytes."

Comment: Don't try to write to the file while you're still reading it! Push the opening of the file output stream later, once you've loaded the workbook into memory

Comment: tell me changes i need to make in code. i have tried every thing. I am not able to understand any logic any more

Comment: Can you show where and how you have declared the variable "last"?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void excelWriter(DTNHost sender, DTNHost peer) {
    String fileName = "Results.xls";
    int last = 0;
    try {

        File file = new File(fileName);
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        HSSFSheet worksheet = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        POIFSFileSystem lPOIfs = null;
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {

                fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                lPOIfs = new POIFSFileSystem(fin);
                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(lPOIfs);
                worksheet = workbook.getSheet("POI Worksheet");
                last = worksheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;

                fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            // create new file
            try {

                fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            worksheet = workbook.createSheet("POI Worksheet");

        }
        HSSFRow row = worksheet.createRow(last);
        HSSFCell cellA1 = row.createCell((int) 0);
        cellA1.setCellValue(sender + " and " + peer);
        HSSFCell cellB1 = row.createCell((int) 1);
        cellB1.setCellValue("mobility");
        HSSFCell cellC1 = row.createCell((int) 2);
        cellC1.setCellValue("angleOfArival");
        HSSFCell cellD1 = row.createCell((int) 3);
        cellD1.setCellValue("connectionTime");
        System.out.println("Data written");
        workbook.write(fout);
        fout.flush();
        fout.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //// End
}
```

Above method works,the OutputStream is opened once the worksheet is loaded,have removed the line `HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);` since its redundant,you already have the worksheet instance from which the lastRowNum can be obtained.The statement `HSSFRow row = worksheet.createRow(last++);` uses post increment operator,so it would keep writing to the same row,the value of "last" variable would get incremented only after this statement gets executed.

Comment: And the if-else condition to set the last row value is also removed.Try this and check if it gives you the expected output(some values are hardcoded as your complete code was not available).